# In Stargate: Atlantis can Wraith survive extreme weather?

Tags: stargate, science

I know there was an episode where a Wraith had been found on a planet near Atlantis.  I also know that Sheppard found a patch of ice in the shade.  What I don't know is the science behind it.  How cold would it have to be at night to leave ice formations like that?  And is it proof that wraith can indeed survive in extreme conditions?

Comment: Doesn't have to be particularly extreme weather. I'm from New England, and I can remember running into patches of snow in the woods well into spring.